# Get margin-top value from transcluded block's child element

Tags: angularjs, fullpage.js

My question is based on the image here [image]

The above uses the angular plugin br-fullpage (angular version of the jquery's fullpage.js plugin) to create a vertical scrolling website. However unlike fullpage.js, br-fullpage is somewhat lacking, and makes it hard for me to determine the current page being displayed on the screen. The only way that i can possibly use (unless if i didn't aware of other methods) to determine which page is being displayed right now, is by using the margin-top value (yellow highlighted).

However everytime i tried to get the margin-top value, i always get 0px instead of the highlighted value. I don't understand what is the problem with this, and it makes me hard to do the animation if i don't know which page that i am currently on when the page is refreshed.

So how can i get the correct margin-top value below? Or is there any other method that i can use to know the current active page displayed on the screen?

Thanks

Comment: I'm wondering why can't you just use the [official fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/). The one you are using seems much more basic and limited by just looking at the code.

Comment: Hi Alvaro. I tried but somehow fullpage.js is not working with the Angular project that i am currently working on. I read on your fullpage's git page about using fullpage in Angular, and i tried to follow all the guidances given by you, but still not working.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem if you know how to work with it. (destroy and initialize it when necessary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use [`sessionStorage.getItem('br-fullpage-index')`](https://github.com/BjornRombaut/br-fullpage/blob/master/app/br-fullpage.js#L29)? This won't give you the margin, but should contain the current page index.

Comment: Gosh this is brilliant but somehow making me feel stupid for not noticing this after few days of debugging. Thanks Matthew!